# How to setup a simple testing environemnt for knative eventing testing?

Tags: vagrant, serverless, knative

I wanted to start learning Knative and specially `Knative Eventing` part. I am struggling more than two weeks with setting up the environment.
There is always an error happening. Sometimes kubernetes stuck on `ImagePullBackOFF`, sometimes `ErrPullImage`.

I installed `k3s` and When I installed `gloo` for knative it just says that there is no environemnt variable as `kubeconfig`... and lots and lots of other errors.

Could somebody help me setup a tesing environment (using `vagrant` etc.) or direct me to a github page or a place where I could actually get some files and codes so that I can get my hands into knative and do something to learn it?

Please help me! I highly appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the answer to the issue you are facing but knative eventing seems not to have been released for gloo yet: https://github.com/solo-io/gloo/issues/753

Comment: yeah its obvious! gloo is for api gateway which is used with knative serving. knative eventing is independent.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out, Eventing does not depend on the `network` layer, it depends solely on Serving (which in turn depends on a `network` layer such as Gloo).